# Multi-org integration steps: do I need multiple integration users?

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, multi-org

We asked support to enable the multi-org connector for our marketing cloud account.

The desired outcome would be to have our parent BU connected to our CRM production org, while the child BU would be connected to our UAT sandbox.

We already have a working integration between our parent BU and our production environment, and we now need to connect the child BU to our UAT crm org.

I wonder though: do we need to follow the same steps as a normal marketing cloud connect integration? It is specified in [the official guide](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/marketing-cloud-connect/get-started-with-mc-connect) that multi-org setup is not covered there, so I'm wondering wether there's something different to do.

For instance, do I need to create another integration user on marketing cloud? Are there any other steps I am missing?

Answer (score 2):

Definitely!

We had 1 Salesforce instance connecting to a Multi-Org Marketing Cloud instances.

After a lot of tests and asking support, the only way to get stable sync was having 1 integration user in SF for each business unit in Marketing Cloud. That for Marketing Cloud Connect.

But, also, be aware of setup if Marketing Cloud Connect in the Sales Cloud side, because  you can only set 1 integration user there, so that user needs access on all business units. That's mandatory, for example, if you want to use Salesforce Data as Journey Entry.

Now it's been working for six months without problems.